# iOS webapp splash screen caching

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net

In reference to "Specifying a Launch Screen Image" from:
 https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

Is launch.png cached on first use then used locally or does it get fetched from the Internet each time?

The reason I ask is we were thinking of programatically cycling the png every day (up to 7 times, one for each day of the week). E.g. Having <%=strFileName %> in place of launch.png.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cycle the image in the launch screen in any way. The only thing you can do is that you make the launch screen white (or some other color if more approrpriate) and then that you show some page as quickly as possible that will contain your 'fake' launch screen content.